# Sub-setting a spatial point data frame in R

Tags: r, adehabitathr

I am trying to subset a spatial point data frame using the function subset as follows:

```
    data(puechabonsp)
    Chou.subset <- subset(puechabonsp,puechabonsp$relocs$Name=="Chou")
```

I was expecting to get all rows of the individual named "Chou" but instead, I got an empty list.
Obviously I am doing it wrong and would apprentice some help.

Thanks!
Idan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `puechabonsp` variable contains 2 parts, a fixed map in the `$map` part and some tracks in the `$relocs` part. If you only want to know the locations where a specific animal is you can do this.

```
Chou.subset <- puechabonsp$relocs[puechabonsp$relocs$Name=='Chou',]
```